# Managing Access for Test and Staging Org for ISV

Tags: user-management

As an ISV with I expect to have several types of orgs during my development process.

- Each developer will have it's own **Partner Development Org**
- There will be a **Test Enterprise Org** (created via Partner Portal) for Continuous Integration Process
- There will be a **Packaging Org** where manager packages will be prepared
- There will be a **Staging Org** where packages will be deployed after each iteration and Product Managers will do Acceptance Testing

So now I have a question on how I should create users on these orgs?

For Development Org it's clear - I just create separate login for each developer on the Partner Portal and they request personal Dev Org.

But for other orgs I am not sure what to do:

Imagine I created an Test org for Continuous Integration from Partner Portal and received an email login - i.e. *skozlov@NNdemo.com*. If I want our QA Automation engineer to have an access to this org should I share my credentials with him? Because if I will just add him as a user I need to put his real email in - which will block him from using other Orgs.

Same questions are valid for Packaging Org and Staging Org.

Thank you,
Sergey.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user name isn't the same as the email address, not does it have to be a "real" email address, so long as it looks RFC 2822 compliant (more or less, anyways).

One typical scenario is to create different user accounts in each org with a common naming convention. Let us say that "John Doe" is a developer that needs multiple developer logins for your contrieved example. Here might be his logins:

```
jdoe@pdo.contoso.com
jdoe@teo.contoso.com
jdoe@po.contoso.com
jdoe@so.contoso.com
```

In this case, all four accounts will have the same *email* address: jdoe@contoso.com, but will have unique login for each organization.

Comment: Thank you - I've already understood that, but just couldn't answer my own questions because of lack of reputation.I would also add that "User License" and "Profile" fields that can help one to differentiate between fake production users and administrative development users on Staging Environment - this turned to be very helpful.